# How to make the main character fall in love with the love interest?

Tags: characters, romance

So I'm new to writing stories and I have thought about the plot too, it's about a girl who gets a chance to work in another country (She's a physiotherapist).She visits their and her patient is an old man who's son will be her love interest, Also love interest's brother would also interfere between them but it would be the love interest only in the end! But I don't know how to make them fall in love with each, I'm finding it very difficult, I would love to hear your ideas!

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! Questions asking what to write are off-topic here, so we can't tell you how your specific romance should unfold, but we can give you more general advice about how to write a romance that develops in a believable fashion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you make two characters fall in love?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/38559/how-do-you-make-two-characters-fall-in-love)

Answer (score 4):

### Love can't be forced. It happens naturally.

You've probably heard "no means no" in the real world as applied to relationships, dating and consent. Unsurprisingly, the same principle applies in your own writing. If a character is deeply in love with another character, pursues them endlessly, and generally does all the right things to try and win their heart, but the other character simply isn't interested, your romance isn't going to work out at best, and it will just come across as creepy and stalker-ish at worst. **Make sure both characters are mutually interested in each other.** Even if one of them "plays hard to get" and doesn't show their interest at first, and there's some playful cat-chasing-mouse involved, the mutual attraction of both characters, even if it's hidden at first, is the most important element of a romance. Your readers will be able to tell *very* easily if you are forcing one character into it.

Think about these questions for each of your characters:

- **Why do they find the other character attractive or interesting?** What is it specifically that draws them in? Maybe the other character is courageous and heroic, going on wild adventures, and that quality tugs at their longing for excitement in their life. Maybe the other character is very intelligent and well-spoken, and provides them with intellectual stimulation and excites their mind. Or maybe they just completely hit it off the first time they meet each other, and can talk about anything for hours on end. There can be any number of reasons why a connection happens, but the connection *must* occur for the romance to start. It's not always just "love at first sight" and pure physical attraction - there usually needs to be more to build on.
- **What do they have in common?** Do they have shared hobbies or interests? Are they both sporty, or nerdy, or athletic? What kinds of topics and activities can they bond over? It's sometimes fun to have an "opposites attract" scenario where the two characters are wildly different, but even then, they need to have *some* things they can connect with each other on, even if it's just liking tennis or riding horses or having terrible in-laws.
- **In what ways do they show their interest? What is their "love language"?** You've probably heard that people in the real world have different "love languages" - some people are physical, others emotional, still others psychological, and etc. Figure out what the love language of each of your characters is. How do they show it to the other character? What are their usual means of communicating affection? **Does it fit well with the love language of the other character?** Or is there a disconnect or miscommunication that creates drama?
- **Do they see the flaws of the other character? Can they accept them?** A true romance is not about "changing" or "fixing" somebody, even if it is an unfortunately common thought in the real world. If your characters truly love each other, they will be willing to see, understand, and accept the other person's flaws and love them anyway, and communicate with each other to work on their weak spots. What are those flaws? What does each character see in the other that isn't always perfect? Do they ever talk about it, or even argue or fight about it? Is that something that drives a wedge between them?

It's tricky to give more specific advice on "making" two characters fall in love, because the process can be so baffling in the real world. We don't always know why we fall in love with people, or what to do next, or how to confess our feelings. It's a confusing and chaotic part of our lives, and that might end up being reflected in your writing. And that's okay. It makes it feel *real.*

Comment: This is a great question to answer, but I'm not sure I can say enough that you haven't already said to make a separate answer. +1 It could maybe use some awkward sexual attraction to help fuel the romance, because sexual attraction is to romance what booze is to sex.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've been able to determine most romance starts with a spark (or a moment) between the two people. It doesn't have to be special or anything, it just happens (something says click, two emotional/spiritual/romantic puzzle pieces fit together, and so on)...

However, that "interest" does not have to be love at first sight. Sometimes it's even hate at first sight. It's just, from that moment on, they keep obsessing about each other until they realize what's going on.

Then there are complications in the form of luggage, low self-esteem, "surely that glance/smile/sultry gaze was not meant for me?" etc...

If you're aiming for romantic drama these complications need to be [internal and emotional](https://www.dummies.com/education/language-arts/creative-writing/creating-emotional-conflict-and-tension-in-a-romance-novel/) rather than external/intellectual.

For instance, having one of the two being kidnapped is an external complication, and while it might make nice drama, it will not make romantic drama.

On the other hand, having backstory (bad past relationships, emotional wounds, betrayals, etc) or psychology (low self-esteem, fear of closeness/failure/betrayal, etc) interfere with the plot is more akin to romance.

To do this well [the love interest](https://www.well-storied.com/blog/the-dos-and-donts-of-crafting-your-storys-love-interest) needs to be more than just a love interest. I.e. the romantic complications should probably come from both characters, not just the main character.

[The romance genre](https://blog.reedsy.com/romance-subgenres/) has some very strict rules for what you can and cannot do. This is maybe only interesting if you want to send your manuscript to a romance publisher, and even more so if you're aiming for a specific subgenre.

Otherwise, romantic subplots can be as close to a romance novel or as far removed from them as needed.

Your target genre will determine how important these rules are for you.